# Inquiries on Cloudflare Caching works?

Tags: caching, browser-cache, cloudflare

[image: Cloudflare Caching Expiration]

I would like to ask about a few things about cloudflare since this is fairly new to me. Please do direct me to the correct forum if I am asking this in the wrong place.

We have an issue right now where a user needs to clear his/her cache before they can successfully log in after a password reset. So I was looking for a way to force a user to clear his/her cache when visiting our website and found 
[This topic about forcing a user to clear cache](https://discuss.flarum.org/d/5358-force-browser-cache-clear) if I am not mistaken it was advised here that we can adjust the browser cache expiration in Cloudflare so that the users would be force to reload everything after the set time in Cloudflare. My question now is how will this affect the page speed of the site and how do I determine how many hours will I set it to, to avoid any problems?

Answer (score 0):

The proper forum (aside from StackOverflow) is https://community.cloudflare.com/c/setup

CloudFlare's cache applies to static resources like images, css files, and javascript files. *Pages are not cached* by CloudFlare. Browsers... well, you can't control them all.

But if you really want to force a browser to not cache a page, you can send it some headers. Here is some coldfusion code to accomplish that, in case you're using that language:

```
<cfheader
    name="Expires"
    value="0">
<cfheader
    name="Expires"
    value="Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT">
<cfheader
    name="Cache-Control"
    value="no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate">
<cfheader
    name="Cache-Control"
    value="post-check=0, pre-check=0">
```